# Make loop in a table using ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have a table like this:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="car in $data">
       <td>
          ...
       </td>
    </tr>
```

i want to display 4 `td` until make a `tr`

I would like to implement this code:

> $ i = 0,  then each pass of the loop $ i ++  and when i == $ 4 then
>   you create a new line (TR) and gives  you $ i = 0

how can i do that ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is a solution you are looking for:

```
  <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="car in cars" ng-if="$index % 4 == 0">
        <td ng-repeat="car in cars.slice($index, $index + 4)">
        {{car}}
        </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
```

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6kmvLya9/1/).

Another option is to properly organize data inside `Controller` like already suggested by @rpadovani.

Answer (score 1):

So you want 4 tds in each tr?
Here you go:

```
<tr ng-repeat="car in $data">
    <td data-ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3]">
      do something
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `$data` an array of arrays, so the structure is like this: `[[a1, a2, a3, a4], [b1, b2, b3, b4]]` and then you use this code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
    <td ng-repeat="car in row">
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
```